# Spark Scala: split data frame in multiple data frames after x rows

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

i am looking for a way to split a data frame in multiple data frames after x rows. Because i want to use the method multiple times it would be cool to parameterize it. For example, i have a dataframe like this with a few thousends rows:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>A</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>C</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4 .. </td>
    <td>..</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

After x rows, i want to separated it in two, three, or x data frames. To make it more understandable, i will try to explain the logic of the method i am thinking about.

```
def divideDF(df: DataFrame, delimiter: Integer): Seq[DataFrame] = {
  val num = df.count
  val start = 0
  val end = fn.round(num/delimiter) // this is the number of dfs i want to receive
  val i = 0

  while(i <= end){
    // split df in multiple data frames
  }  
}
```

i really appreciate your help, if you need more information, i will provide it :)

Comment: Why do u need multiple dataframes? just split it to more partitions if you want more parallelisem...

Comment: i want to write these data frames to another database frequently. Because of this, i need a method to handle this job

Answer (score 0):

Try the `randomSplit` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object SampleFoo extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .master("local[2]")
    .getOrCreate()

  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

  import spark.implicits._

  val splits = (1 to 100)
    .toDS
    .randomSplit(Array(.25, .25, .25, .25), 1)

  println(splits.length)

  splits.head.printSchema()

  splits.foreach(s => {
    s.show(40)
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response rad i, but i don't know how i am able to split the data frame dynamically. Could you help me please ?